# What is the meaning of the negative solution of the pythagorean theorem?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $a^2=b^2+c^2$, then $a=\pm\sqrt{b^2+c^2}$

1) What is the meaning of the negative solution for $a$?

2) How could I visualize that?

3) Similar question for the law of cosines. What is the meaning of the negative solution of $a^2=b^2+c^2-2bc\cos{\alpha}$

Comment: In both cases $a>0$

Comment: In geometry negative lengths are only possible if you give lines an orientation so that lengths measure $A$ to $B$ are positive, but $B$ to $A$ are negative.

Comment: @almagest What would that look like?

Comment: @Roman83 $-\sqrt{b^2+c^2}$ is negative... so then $a<0$

Comment: As said, @almagest, $BC^2=AC^2+AB^2$. Then 
$$BC=\sqrt{AC^2+AB^2}$$
$$CB=-\sqrt{AC^2+AB^2}$$